# Method 'convert' not found in \AmrShawky\LaravelCurrency\Facade\Currency

Tags: laravel, currency, laravel-package

I am using package :- https://github.com/amrshawky/laravel-currency to convert the price
In the docs iam using simple line of code.

```
$currency_conversion = Currency::convert()->from("USD")->to("INR")->amount(10000)->round(2)->get();
```

but it is giving error Method 'convert' not found in \AmrShawky\LaravelCurrency\Facade\Currency

I use use AmrShawky\LaravelCurrency\Facade\Currency; but it is not working

Comment: the project is archived.